# Can we get rid of the confusing number 10k users see?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

All users with sufficiently high reputation (2k on beta, 10k on graduated sites) see a little number next to their review button indicating the number of reviews waiting *everyone* even if they have emptied all the queues they can.
This is very, very confusing, especially since the UI does not explain what the number is.

Can we please get rid of that number, at least for those users that have emptied all the queues they can?
If this is impossible for some reason (I would like to know why), could there at least be an explanation on the review page so that numbers add up?

I have learned from my SE experience that such a number indicates that I should react to something.
This is also supported by my general instincts in online systems.
When I click the number only to end up on a review page with empty queues, I get annoyed and confused instead of feeling gratification.
Generally SE rewards moderator work with gratification quite well, but I find this number to be counter-productive.

I had to [ask a meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/162/79) to figure out what that number means, and it seems that others are annoyed and confused about it, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've [answered your other meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/165/12) with what I believe is the most likely explanation for the number currently showing in the counter.  Here I'll focus on this feature request.

You say:

> When I click the number only to end up on a review page with empty queues, I get annoyed and confused

I know what you mean.  When I first got this "10k counter," on a different site, I found it extremely annoying.  I still don't think it's particularly ideal, and many other users of Stack Exchange have expressed similar sentiments: see the comments of [this post announcing the implementation of the feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/300411).

However, in defense of the feature as currently implemented, two things can be said:

- Providing an personalized counter to every user would be highly resource intensive.  The counter appears with every page load, unlike the numbers on the Review page, which are only calculated while actively reviewing.
- It gives 10k users (2k on beta sites) a high-level overview of the state of the site.  If the counter is going up, we know that we need more people to be accessing the review queues.

As I said, I'm not a huge fan of the counter as it is: it's distracting and less helpful than the counter for suggested edits that other users have.  But it does have one benefit, which makes me hesitant to get rid of it.

Still, if you *really* want to do something about this, you can support related feature requests on Meta Stack Exchange like these:

- [Please dim the color of the review task counter when there are no actionable tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231051/300411)
- [Review Count - Fix It or Lose It](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238472/300411)

Alternatively, you can take more extreme action—some users have employed ad blockers to prevent the counter from being rendered on their screens.